# How to Convert search nearby places query to Laravel eloquent ORM?

Tags: sql, laravel, orm, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I am using autocomplete mapbox search places option to search nearby places. I have sql query, it executes correct. But I want to convert exact SQL query into Laravel eloquent. I tried but caught with an error: **A non-numeric value encountered**

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT * , (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( 12.91 - latitude) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( 12.91 * pi()/180) * COS(latitude * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( 74.85 - longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) 
as distance from vehicles
having  distance <= 10 
order by distance
```

I want to use exact query in controller

**In Laravel used same query**

```
$vehicles = $vehicles->select('*',(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POW(SIN(( $request->location_lat - 'latitude') *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( $request->location_lat * pi()/180) * COS('latitude' * pi()/180) * POW(SIN(( $request->location_long - 'longitude') * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))))
           ->having(distance <= 10)
           ->orderBy(distance,'ASC')
           ->get();
```

How it can be done?

Comment: Why you are not writing same calculation with php functions then pass value to query?

Comment: I am new to laravel.  I think No, calculation needs table column values